# To find the probability of the event associated with the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ independent random variables which have a Bernoulli distribution:

$$X_i = \{0, 1\},\;\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1) = p,\;\mathbb{P}(X_i = 0) = q, \; p + q = 1$$

And define: 
$$S_n = X_1 + \ldots + X_n,\;X_0 = 0$$ 
$$\nu_k = \min\{n \ge 1 : S_n = k\}$$

I need to find the probability $$\mathbb{P} (S_{2\nu_1} = \nu_1)$$

I did the following calculation: $$\mathbb{P} (S_{2\nu_1} = \nu_1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(S_{2k} = k, \nu_1 = k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(S_{2k} = k, S_1 \ne 1, \ldots, S_{k-1} \ne 1, S_k = 1)$$

I want to write $$\mathbb{P}(S_{2k} = k, S_1 \ne 1, \ldots, S_{k-1} \ne 1, S_k = 1) = \mathbb{P} (S_{2k} = k)\mathbb{P}(S_1 \ne 1)\ldots\mathbb{P}(S_{k-1} \ne 1)\mathbb{P}(S_k = 1)$$

This can be done if the events $(S_{2k} = k)$, $(S_1 \ne 1)$, $\ldots$, $(S_{k-1} \ne 1)$, $(S_k = 1)$ are independent. Are these events independent? If not then do you have any other ideas for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:

- $\nu_1=\min\{k\mid X_k=1\}$ hence $\nu_1$ has a geometric distribution with $P(\nu_1=k)=pq^{k-1}$ for every $k\geqslant1$
- $S_{\nu_1}=1$ with full probability hence $[S_{2\nu_1}=\nu_1]=[S_{2\nu_1}-S_{\nu_1}=\nu_1-1]$
- conditionally on $[\nu_1=k]$, $S_{2\nu_1}-S_{\nu_1}$ is distributed like $S_k$

Thus, $$P(S_{2\nu_1}=\nu_1)=\sum_{k\geqslant1}P(\nu_1=k)P(S_k=k-1)=\sum_{k\geqslant1}pq^{k-1}p^{k-1}q=\frac{pq}{1-pq}.$$